# Graphviz: How to add label to arrows if nodes already have a label

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am making a graph using graphviz dot.

like this

```
digraph protocol {
    label="Protocol workflow";
    node[shape=box, style=rounded];

    a[label="Byte received"];
    b[label="Is start delimiter?", shape=diamond];
    c[label="Recv length [n, 1B]"]; c1[label="Set count=n"];
    d[label="Recv 1 payload byte and decrement count"];
    e[label="count > 0", shape=diamond];
    f[label="Recv CRC [2B]"];
    g[label="Is CRC valid?", shape=diamond];

    a -> b -> c -> c1 -> d -> e -> f -> g;
    e -> d;
```

}

Problem is that to some arrows I need to add yes no labels but I don't know how I could do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add labels to edges like this:

```
e -> f [label="Yes"];
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I tried it once but failed, then noticed that if write only one edge per line then it works

Comment: Do you know if one can add labels to each end (the start and end) of the edge too?